# Is it possible to callback to multiple listeners?

Tags: java, callback

Is it possible to set multiple listeners using callbacks?

I am trying to understand how the callbacks work and I am trying to figure out it that's what I need.

I have one UDP messaging class which receives/sends messages. When I parse certain messages, I would like to update multiple UI classes.

At the moment I have something like this:

```
class CommInt {

    private OnNotificationEvent notifListener;

    public setNotificationListener(OnNotificationEvent notifListner) {
        /* listener from one UI */
        this.notifListener = notifListener;
    }

    private parseMsg(Message msg) {

        if (msg.getType() == x) {
            notifListener.updateUI();
        }

    }

}
```

I need to update another UI as well. The other UI will use the same interface but the body will be different.

How is it possible call all listener which are implemented from that interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very likely that you will need to make a List of listeners, then iterate through each one calling `updateUI()`. Of course, you also need an `addListener()` method so that you don't overwrite.

```
class CommInt {

  private List <OnNotificationEvent> listeners= new ArrayList <OnNotificationEvent>();


  public void addNotificationListener(OnNotificationEvent notifListner) {
    listeners.add (notifListener);
  }

  private void parseMsg(Message msg) {

    if (msg.getType() == x) {
      for (notifListener : listeners){
        notifListener.updateUI();
      }
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

With your code: no, because you're recording using a single variable. Replace that with a variable length container, and it will take as many listeners as you like:

```
class CommInt {
  private ArrayList<NotificationListener> listeners =
    new ArrayList<NotificationListener>();

  public addNotificationListener(NotificationListener listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
  }

  private doSomething(Something input) {
    if (input.hasProperty(x)) {
      for (NotificationListener l: listeners) {
        l.inputHasProperty(x);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also note the different naming. The Java convention is to call things after what they are, or do. If you have a list of listeners, make them implement the NotificationListener interface and store them as such.

Also, the "set" is now an "add" (because we can add an infinite number of them), and the callback is named after the test we perform to determine whether or not the callback is necessary. This keeps your code clean since it forces your method name and the code in it to make sense.

"updateUI" based on "message is type ..." doesn't make a lot of sense, whereas "l.clearDialogs()" on "msg.type = Message.CLEAR_DIALOGS" would.

Comment: Thanks. The code I wrote was just example and does not correspond to the actual code.

Comment: no worries. although it's usually a good idea to make sure your example code conforms to language-specific style guides so people don't focus on that rather than the original question ^_^